# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x1f'

Tags: python, error-handling, pickle

I am having problem in unpickling a .pkl file and editing it. I tried the following code but it shows error. How could I proceed?

```
import pickle
import numpy as np

with open('speech_emotion_data.pkl', 'rb') as pickle_file:
    new_data = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

it shows error as:

> UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x1f'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load CIFAR-10 dataset: Invalid load key '\x1f'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121556/unable-to-load-cifar-10-dataset-invalid-load-key-x1f)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049688/what-causes-the-error-pickle-unpicklingerror-invalid-load-key

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, it seems that Pickle files have some troubles when compressed. A temporal solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521660/in-pandas-how-read-a-pickle-file-that-throws-unpickling-error-invalid-load-key), adding the following:

`gzip` or `xz` as parameters to `pd.read_pickle` function, or, as in your case, using `gzip.open`

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('speech_emotion_data.pkl', 'rb') as pickle_file:
```