# SageMaker Experiments: UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x1f'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I am new to Data Science and have been trying to use SageMaker Experiments to create an extremely simple model. Using SageMaker Experiments, I trained a model using a CSV dataset. The model was output to S3, and I am now trying to load that model into a Jupyter Notebook and run a batch transform test on it.

However, I am getting an error when trying to use the following block of code provided in the SageMaker docs that is supposed to help me import the model. [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html)

```
import pickle as pkl
import tarfile
import xgboost

t = tarfile.open('model.tar.gz', 'r:gz')
t.extractall()

model = pkl.load(open(model_file_path, 'rb'))
```

The error is occurring at pkl.load:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-81639df86023> in <module>
      6 t.extractall()
      7 
----> 8 model = pkl.load(open(model_file_path, 'rb'))
      9 
     10 

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x1f'.
```

**Note:** model_file_path is 'model.tar.gz'

Because I am so new at this, I do not know if it is an error with what I have done, or if there is something about how SageMaker Experiments does something that I am missing. I have tried referencing other stackoverflow posts that contain this error, but they don't seem to directly apply (to my understanding) to my error. ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049688/what-causes-the-error-pickle-unpicklingerror-invalid-load-key) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121556/unable-to-load-cifar-10-dataset-invalid-load-key-x1f))

Any expert advice on SageMaker Experiments or the SageMaker v2 SDK would be extremely helpful to this newbie trying to break into the space. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like your issue is being caused by SageMaker Experiments. This is either an issue with your `model.tar.gz` file itself or the way you are loading it using `pkl`.

`model.tar.gz` should contain the pickle file for the model itself. You can then extract the pickle file from `model.tar.gz` and load that into your model object.

Alternatively, you could use the `XGBoostModel` class to create a model from the `model.tar.gz` file itself. Refer to the following [docs](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/xgboost/using_xgboost.html#) for more details on loading a pre-trained XGBoost Model.

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own